# The Definition of a subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am confused about  the definition of a subsequence,in my skript is writtern the following definition

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $F$. Let $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strongly monotonically increasing sequence with $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is called a subsequence.

However I cannot understand why monotonically increasing? After the definition is also given an example with subsequences, but the subsequences are monotonicaly decresing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *indices* into the sequence are strictly increasing. $n_k := 1, 3, 6, 8, \dots$ (an increasing sequence) leads to the subsequence $a_1, a_3, a_6, a_8, \dots$ which need not be increasing.

Comment: so you mean the order of the sequence memebers should be keeped ? Such that if we have the sequence an=1/n with a1 = 1, a2= 1/2, a3 =1/3 the subsequence could have a2 , a3...  but not a2,a3,a1 ?

Comment: Correct. A "subsequence" is an infinite selection of members from the sequence, where order is important: you have to keep selecting strictly later elements of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be more intuitive to define a subsequence this way.

Say we have some sequence $(a_n)$. Take some particular indices of that sequence, call it $(n_k)$, to define a sequence of the indices, and ensure that $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < ...$.

Then we define the subsequence of $(a_n)$, which we'll call $(a_{n_k})$, by this sequence. The first term is $a_{n_1}$, where $n_1$ is the first index in your sequence of indices, for example.

What this loosely ultimately amounts to is basically a means of picking and choosing members of the sequence to form your subsequence. You look through the sequence $(a_n)$ and pick the first term you want, calling it $a_{n_1}$. Then you continue further into the sequence (you never ever look at the previous terms), and pick a second term from $(a_n)$ you want, calling it $a_{n_2}$, and so on and so forth.

Another intuitive, loose way to look at is that the sequence $(a_{n_k})$ is a sequence like $(a_n)$, just with some of the terms skipped over, whichever ones you don't want. So if you took a subsequence consisting of every even-indexed term, the subsequence is basically $(a_n)$, but you deleted every term of odd index (i.e. you got rid of $a_1,a_3,a_5,$ etc.

The definition you were given mostly formalizes this overall idea.

In particular, the strongly monotonically increasing condition, for example, formalizes this idea of "don't look back." This definition enables some useful results we like - for example, this definition of subsequence ensures that convergent sequences have all their subsequences converging to the same limit as the sequence itself. If we remove this condition, we could, for example, just have subsequences bounce back and forth between the same two terms - not particularly interesting or useful, especially compared to the previous, no?

Comment: And why wouldn't we define a subsequence of a given sequence $(a_n)$ as $(a_{\varphi(n)})$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi(n)=+\infty$, without assuming $\varphi$ to be monotonically increasing ? It seems to me that the aforementioned property of any subsequence of any convergent sequence to convert to the same limit would still be true ...

Comment: That is a good question; I don't have a good answer for you at this time.

Comment: Now that I look at this more: I believe that opens us up to the cases of repeated indices, depending on the $\varphi$ chosen. Ignoring that, you would still have a sequence of indices that could be ordered in the usual way: you have a $\varphi(1),\varphi(2),\varphi(3)$, etc. One can then define $n_k$ as the $k$th smallest  of the $\varphi(n)$, and restore the original definition. So I'm not sure you lose or gain much by that.